# Will on hit magic damage proc maw of malmortius's passive lifeline?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the Offense skill tree there is a mastery that gives you +magic damage on hit from 5% of your total AP.

If a champion you are attacking has maw of malmortius or hex drinker will the lifeline passive get proced from the attack?

There are also items that give +magic damage on hit like Lich Bane or Nasthor's Tooth. Do the items also proc the passive, lifeline?

And finally if only one of these proc lifeline will the shield block the magic damage of the other while the shield is up?

Comment: why shouldn't they proc it?

Comment: Was wondering, I don't build Maw or Hex very often to notice it getting proced in these types of situations, Only when there is some one extremely burst-y and very fed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maw of Malmortius says:

> Unique – Lifeline: Upon taking magic damage that would reduce health below 30%, grants a shield that absorbs 400 magic damage for 5 seconds (90 second cooldown).

This seems quite clear, upon taking magic damage (from any source including things like masteries, Darius's passive, Lich Bane, etc) it creates a shield that blocks magic damage (from any source) so long as that damage is taken during the 5 second shield duration.

Comment: I can attest that MF [Impure shots](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Miss_Fortune#Impure_Shots) passive triggers the shield... but that Darius that had it died anyway.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd expect since it only blocks the magic damage and MF is doing mostly physical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will proc , If anything drops them low , ignite , attacked by minions . ANYTHING  can proc the maw/hexdrinker passive .